# How to Integrate the gcov report into azure devops pipeline PublishCodeCoverageResults?

Tags: azure, devops, gcov

I have managed to use gcov to generate the code coverage report (xml or html), how to integrate it in azure devops?

I read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v1?view=azure-pipelines
and it seems it does not support gcov report/format

Thanks